# How to parse a json requestbody in post request

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

I am trying to parse JSON and get the values of the keys. But the issue which i am facing is that the JSON can be very dynamic. It can have a key sometime and sometime it won't have it. In addition to that I need to transform the given json to form a select SQL query. so the JSON would be something like below :-

JSON:-

```
{
  "where": {
    "AND":{
      "column1": {"in": ["x","x1"]},
      "column2": {"in": ["y","y1"]},
      "OR":[
        {"column3": {"eq": "x3"}},
        {"column4": {"eq": "y4"}}
      ]
    },
    "column5": {"between": ["x5","y5"]},
    "not": {"column6": {"eq": "x6"}}
  }
}
```

based on this i need to extract the select columns and the where condition.

Please note:- the json can have different where condition all the time.

I tired writing a code for JSON parser but could not take it to the point where it successfully parse the JSON to form the query.

But when i try to call the function as getKey(json,"and"); i get the error
`Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]`

Code:-

```
    public static void getKey(JSONObject json, String key){
        boolean exists = json.has(key);
        Iterator<?> keys;
        String nextKeys;
        if(!exists){
            keys =json.keys();
            while (keys.hasNext()){
                nextKeys = (String) keys.next();
                    if(json.get(nextKeys) instanceof JSONObject){
                        if(exists == false){
                            getKey(json.getJSONObject(nextKeys),key);
                        }
                    }else if (json.get(nextKeys) instanceof JSONArray){
                        JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray(nextKeys);
                        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            String jsonArrayString = jsonArray.get(i).toString();
                            JSONObject innerJSON = new JSONObject(jsonArrayString);
                            if(exists == false){
                                getKey(innerJSON,nextKeys);
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }else {
            System.out.println(json.get(key).toString());
        }
}
```